# Javascript chrome extension not clicking button with click()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I would like to use a chrome extension to automatically control a website.
For example it should click a button.
This is my code:

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "FTB",
    "description": "my extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

**popup.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Fill</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2 id="htwo">Button presser</h2>
        <button id="press">Go to activity tab</button>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
function injectTheScript() {
    // Gets all tabs that have the specified properties, or all tabs if no properties are specified (in our case we choose current active tab)
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        // Injects JavaScript code into a page
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, { file: 'utilities.js' });
    });
}
// adding listener to your button in popup window
document.getElementById('press').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript);
```

**utilities.js**

```
/**
 * Gets the desired element on the client page and clicks on it
 */
function goToActivityTab() {
    var activityTab = document.getElementsByClassName('ut-tab-bar-item')[2];
    activityTab.click();
}

goToActivityTab();
```

So my guess is that there is something I miss in the utilities.js file.
Strange thing is that if I for example instad of trying to `.click()` the button, I would go and change the style of the button it works. For example changing the background of it to pink like that:

```
activityTab.style['background'] = "#FF00FF"
```

I also tried to access [2] of the activityTab array when I try to click it instead of adding it to the `document.get...` like that:
`activityTab[2].click()`
But this also didn't work.

Why is it not performing the `.click()`?

Comment: Try `activityTab.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}))`

Comment: not working either

Comment: It means the site listens to a different event e.g. `mousedown` or `mouseup` or the selector is wrong. Open the [Event listeners panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57j37.png), click through the hierarchy and try finding the events.

Comment: I am getting this: https://i.imgur.com/nXUInPB.png

Comment: following error i get :

utilities.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: activityTab.click() is not a function
    at goToActivityTab (utilities.js:8)
    at utilities.js:11

Comment: I actually think my approach with .click is not correct. But in this case google is not my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was as guessed by @wOxxOm !
This code below fixed it for me:

```
function mouseEventClick() {
    const transferWindowNavBtn = document.querySelector('body > main > section > nav > button.ut-tab-bar-item.icon-transfer');
    if (transferWindowNavBtn) {
        //--- Simulate a natural mouse-click sequence.
        triggerMouseEvent(transferWindowNavBtn, 'mouseover');
        triggerMouseEvent(transferWindowNavBtn, 'mousedown');
        triggerMouseEvent(transferWindowNavBtn, 'mouseup');
        triggerMouseEvent(transferWindowNavBtn, 'click');
    } else console.log('ERROR: Transfer Window not visible!');

    function triggerMouseEvent(node, eventType) {
        const clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        clickEvent.initEvent(eventType, true, true);
        node.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
    }
}
```